# Separate workspaces in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, workspaces, gnome-shell, application-switcher

In Ubuntu 16.04 each workspace had a separate 'application space' as it were.  That is, when you were on workspace 1 you could only loop through applications on that workspace.  So I could have, for example, one Firefox instance on workspace 1 and another on workspace 2.  If I was on workspace 1, I could only loop through Firefox instances on that workspace.  But now, in Ubuntu 18.04, there is no such separation: looping through applications on one workspace could suddenly whisk me away to another workspace.  Is there any way to recover this separation of workspaces from Ubuntu 16.04 in 18.04?

Comment: What do you mean by "loop through applications"? How are you doing that?

Comment: I'm using Alt-Tab

Comment: I am also confused by this problem, hoping there is some solution to it.